# Css responsive line between 2 dots

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, responsive

I have to make responsive line between 2 dots:

[image: model]

Is it possible in `css` to write beginning of the connecting line in one `div` and bind it's end with anoter `div`? Is it possible in css or mabye svg? I don't want to use js only for these lines.

If the block has fixed width everything is ok:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem
}

.item__num {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: 400 1.5rem/2rem sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.item__num span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__num_lg {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  font: 400 2.5rem/3rem sans-serif;
}

.item__text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .5rem -1rem 0;
  font: 400 1rem/1.4 sans-serif;
  color: gray;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


/*My non-adaptive solution:*/

.item__num:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: .5rem;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(1) .item__num:before {
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(2) .item__num:before {
  top: .75rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(4) .item__num:before {
  top: -93px;
  left: -46px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(5) .item__num:before {
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>1</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text short</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>The text is a bit bigger, maybe two lines, maybe one, maybe two lines, maybe one</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>3</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text is small, medium text</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>4</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>The text is a bit bigger, maybe two lines, maybe one</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>5</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text is small, medium text</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>6</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text short</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make the same for responsive blocks?

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem
}

.item__num {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: 400 1.5rem/2rem sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.item__num span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__num_lg {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  font: 400 2.5rem/3rem sans-serif;
}

.item__text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .5rem -1rem 0;
  font: 400 1rem/1.4 sans-serif;
  color: gray;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


/*My non-adaptive solution:*/

.item__num:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: .5rem;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(1) .item__num:before {
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(2) .item__num:before {
  top: .75rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(4) .item__num:before {
  top: -93px;
  left: -46px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(5) .item__num:before {
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 166px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>1</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text short</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>The text is a bit bigger, maybe two lines, maybe one, maybe two lines, maybe one</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>3</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text is small, medium text</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>4</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>The text is a bit bigger, maybe two lines, maybe one</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class=item__num><span>5</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text is small, medium text</div>
  </div>

  <div class=item>
    <div class="item__num item__num_lg"><span>6</span></div>
    <div class=item__text>Text short</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the divs are static you can use an SVG to draw a line between them. But if it's responsive you'll have to use javascript/jQuery to update the line, no other options.

Comment: I think you can about 90%. Here is what i tried https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/YxQYyg?editors=1100. I used the viewport units. Issue only comes with the rotate angle which needs to be calculated and i think for that you will definitely need to use js. Another solution is to use background-images as the lines and control their width via vw units and then i think you may achieve 100% responsiveness.